How to use Sublime to Edit Files in Remote Server Using Kerberos Authentication
I am trying to use Sublime Text to edit files in a remote server that I connect with a Kerberos ticket. Normally, I first get a Kerberos ticket, and then I can use open-ssh to connect to the server. The problem is I only have a terminal, vim is good but I am very comfortable with Sublime Text.
I tried using SFTP plugin at Sublime Text, but I can't seem to connect. It just times out. I suspect Sublime does not see the Kerberos ticket. Any ideas?

Times out? That doesn't sound like anything authentication-related. Are you sure both are set up to connect to the same system?
